# std::vector<std::pair<int,std::pair<Bone,std::string> > > not sorting by int?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a `std::vector<std::pair<int,std::pair<Bone,std::string> > >`

I'm trying to sort it with std sort, with the expectation that it is sorted by int, but instead I get 21 errors related to the sort call.

What could be wrong?

Code:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,std::pair<Bone,std::string> > > tempBones;
std::sort(tempBones.begin(),tempBones.end());
```

Errors:

> Error  1   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`  c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  2   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const _Elem *'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  3   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  4   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  5   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  6   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  7   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'` c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  8   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  9   error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'` c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 102
>
> Error  10  error C2676: binary `'<'` : `'const skl::Bone'` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 10
>
> Error  11  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`  c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  12  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const _Elem *'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  13  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  14  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  15  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`    c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  16  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::list<_Ty,_Ax> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  17  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'` c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  18  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'`   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  19  error C2784: `'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)'` : could not deduce template argument for `'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'` from `'const skl::Bone'` c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103
>
> Error  20  error C2676: binary `'<'` : `'const skl::Bone'` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility 103

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why would you expect it to be sorted by `int`? Any `container<T>` is sorted by `T`, and sorting requires that there be a less-than comparison for `T`. Now for `pair<S,T>`, there is an `operator<`, defined as lexicographic ordering, but this requires comparability of both `S` and `T`:

```
// lexicographic compare:
bool operator<(pair<S,T> a, pair<S,T> b)
{
  return a.first < b. first || (!(b.first < a.first) && (a.second < b.second));
  //                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} //                                                     compare second type!
```

Moving down recursively, you need `Bone` to be less-than comparable. Do check, any bet that you didn't implement a comparison operator for that type!

*Edit:* According to your update that is precisely your problem.

*Remark:* You might wonder why lexicographic compare is the default: It's the only sensible comparison for which `!(x < y) && !(y < x)` is identical to `x == y`, provided the same holds for both sub-types individually.

*Update:* If you only want ordering by the first member, you should write a custom comparator predicate, or use a multi-map instead.

Custom comparator:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
bool PairCompareOnlyFirst(const std::pair<S,T> & a, const std::pair<S,T> & b)
{
  return a.first < b.first;
}

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), PairCompareOnlyFirst);
```

Note that `sort` may rearrange elements with the same key. If you want those to maintain their relative ordering, use `stable_sort` instead.

Multimap:

```
typedef std::multimap<int, std::pair<Bone,std::string> > myMapType;
```

The multimap is a more complicated structure than the vector, and its elements are always kept in sorted order by key value, i.e. your `int`. Which one is preferable depends on what you're doing.

Comment: I just want to sort by the first which is an int

Comment: @Milo: Updated to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the error I can't be sure about this, but one thing to note is that std::pair does not just sort by the first value; it also uses the second value if needed to break ties.  In the context of std::map this isn't an issue because internally the map uses a custom comparator instead of the default operator<, but if you sort pairs naturally the ordering may take the second element into account.

Because of this, if you didn't define operator< for Bone, you will get a compiler error because the template code for pair's operator< will try to use it.  On top of that, you'd get some ferocious compiler errors about it, since the compiler will only report the error after instantiating the templates for sort and pair.

Hope this helps!